Movie where a man travels through parallel universes while a creature with a mirror or glass mask/helmet hunts him
I saw the trailer for a relatively recent live-action movie. Possibly 5-6 years old, maybe less.
A man travels through parallel dimensions or parallel universes.
There is a hooded humanoid-like creature with a mirror-like mask/helmet, a mask similar to an alchemist from Vidocq, also with the hood.
The creature is hunting him because he broke the rules of dimensional traveling?

Just to be clear, it's not power armor with a faceplate as per https://i.sstatic.net/4bfYs.jpg?

Em... nope. glass mirror mask with hood

Was this a live action or animated movie?

Live action movie

When did you see the trailer?

Last 2-3 years...
